# Do I need a transit visa to travel to Northern Cyprus?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, turkey, ghanaian-citizens, northern-cyprus

I am a Ghanaian passport holder. Do I need a Turkish transit visa to travel from Moscow to the Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What is your transit point?

Comment: Should we assume that your itinerary includes a stop in Turkey?

Comment: @phoog Any and all trips to Northern Cyprus do

Comment: @Crazydre as I understand it one can cross from the Republic of Cyprus without passing through Turkey.

Comment: @Crazydre one could for example fly to Nicosia without passing through Turkey and then travel by land to Northern Cyprus.

Comment: @phoog "Nicosia" Airport (Ercan) is in Northern Cyprus. Cyprus has Larnaca and Paphos, but the post does not remotely suggest OP's flying to any of those. It says "Turkish republic of Northern Cyprus" and asks about a Turkish transit visa

Comment: @Crazydre so the answer to my question asking for clarification is perhaps "yes."   That doesn't mean my question was unreasonable, as you seem to be implying.

Comment: @phoog Yes, we can definitely assume OP's flying directly to Northern Cyprus, which invariably means a connection (or in rare cases touchdown) in Turkey

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=GH&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&TR=TR&selDest=France&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets
>   for a max. transit time of 24 hours.

So no, you do **not** need a visa